# View error response text in Azure Application Insights

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, azure-web-app-service, azure-application-insights

I've asp.net core 2.1 application, using app insights nuget:

```
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.ApplicationInsights.HostingStartup" 
                  Version="2.1.1" />
```

In the azure portal, I can see failed request and the end to end transaction detail, e.g.:

[image]

Is it possible to see the response text which is more descriptive, or I need to log it manually?

Also on failed POST request, I would like to log posted data

Answer (score 0):

Application Insights SDK does not automatically collect the response body or Post params, but you can write TelemetryInitializers to add any additional properties you'd like collected. As long you can access the POST params or body or anything - you can attach it to the `RequestTelemetry`.

It's important to note that you may not be able to read response body twice, so you won't be able to add it to `RequestTelemetry` via TelemetryInitializer. In those cases, please try the answer below:

https://github.com/Microsoft/ApplicationInsights-aspnetcore/issues/686#issuecomment-388425295

Comment: It's probably not enabled by default since those kind of parameters/body can often contain private information. So OP needs to be careful what they collect here ;)